# get all buttons in app page

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I build a project in java, which suppose get smali code for page in the app, and return all the buttons in the layout of this page.

First, I implemented a parser for the appropriate xml file.
The parser search all the buttons in the page.
It works properly.

However, I have a problem because I noticed that the smali code can add dynamically buttons to the layout of the page. I thought to implement parser for the smali file but I think doesn't make a sense to do that.

I have a 2 ideas but I donwt know if they can be applied:

1) to run on the method onCreate, and add views to the xml file at the same time.
After that, I have the full views in the page layout.

2) use UI hierarchy, which return hierarchy of the views in the page. But I don't know how use it programmatically and get it comfortably.

thanks, Yinon

Answer (score 1):

Run this for your activitie's(or fragment's) ViewGroup and all buttons will be in mButtons.

```
List<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList();

void getAllButtons(ViewGroup v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = v.getChildAt(i);
    if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
        getAllButtons((ViewGroup)child);
    else if(child instanceof Button)
        mButtons.add((Button)child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it although my project is external?
I need to decompile apk, and pass through all the activities and get the buttons.

Comment: The only thing you need is ViewGroup where all the buttons.